# TD Won't Become a Link?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have searched all topics but none work!
I am trying to make a  entirely covered with the  tag, but it won't input any link anywhere in the TD, not even the text!

**HTML**

```
        <table border=1>
            <tr>
                <a href="1.php"><td>A</td></a>
                <a href="2.php"><td>B</td></a>
                <a href="3.php"><td>C</td></a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <a href="4.php"><td>D</td></a>
                <a href="5.php"><td>E</td></a>
                <a href="6.php"><td>F</td></a>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**CSS**

```
            table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border:white;
            background-color:#0078ff;
        }

        td {
            font-size:50px;
            padding:50px;
            text-align:center;
            color:white;
        }
```

I do not see how it can't work. I've already tried doing

```
            td a {
            font-size:50px;
            padding:50px;
            text-align:center;
            color:white;
            display:block;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `a` tag inside `td` and make some change in your css, it will work like you want
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aabpotz7/)

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:white;
    background-color:#0078ff;
}
td {
    font-size:50px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
table a {color:inherit; text-decoration:none}
table td a {display:block; padding:50px}
```

Answer (score 0):

`td` can't be outbound by `a` tag. Try a cheat by using javascript

```
<table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="window.location.href='1.php'">A</td></a>
                <td onclick="window.location.href='2.php'">B</td></a>
                <td onclick="window.location.href='3.php'">C</td></a>
            </tr>
        </table>
```